# Ada generic child instantiation claims to need itself

Tags: generics, ada

I have a generic package with the following signature

```ada
generic
    type T is private;
    with function "="(Left : T; Right : T) return Boolean is <>;
    with function Wide_Wide_Image(Self : T) return Wide_Wide_String is <>;
package Generics.Testing.Assertions is
```

It has a child package with the following signature

```ada
generic
    with function "<"(Left : T; Right : T) return Boolean is <>;
    with function ">"(Left : T; Right : T) return Boolean is <>;
package Generics.Testing.Assertions.Comparisons is
```

I'm trying to instantiate these inside of another package with an interesting problem.

This works fine:

```ada
package Integer_Assertions is new Generics.Testing.Assertions(
    Integer,
    Wide_Wide_Image => Integer'Wide_Wide_Image);
```

Where it gets weird is when I try to instantiate the child package with:

```ada
package Integer_Comparisons is new Integer_Assertions.Comparisons;
```

GPS finds the `Comparisons` package within `Integer_Assertions` just fine, as it should. But the compiler has the two following errors:

```
missing "with Integer_Assertions.Comparisons;"
```

and

```
"Comparisons" not declared in "Integer_Assertions"
```

Okay? But IntelliSense found it fine. I haven't done much Ada development in a while though, so maybe I'm forgetting how to instantiate a generic child of a generic.

So I try the fully qualified non-instance name instead:

```ada
package Integer_Comparisons is new Generics.Testing.Assertions.Comparison;
```

Which failed with:

```
invalid prefix in selected component "Generics.Testing.Assertions"
```

As I remember it should.

How do I actually instantiate the child inside of a package then?

Comment: I assume you have a  `with Generics.Testing.Assertions.Comparisons;`?

Comment: Try instantiating an inner child with the same signature

Comment: It really helps if you provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 5):

Oh, what's happening is that the dependency-graph isn't accurate, and the reason is that you need to **with** the deepest generic in the hierarchy. (eg `with Generics.Testing.Assertions.Comparison;`)

Then you do this:

```
package Integer_Assertions is new Generics.Testing.Assertions
  ( Integer, Wide_Wide_Image => Integer'Wide_Wide_Image );

package Integer_Comparisons is new Integer_Assertions.Comparisons;
```

The reason for this is that without `with`-ing the full dependency-path, the *real* dependency can't be found; this is the difference between nested- and hierarchical-package organization: you don't need to (and can't) `with` the nested units, you **must** with the deepest hierarchical unit(s) that you utilize.

Answer (score 4):

I may be misinterpreting the question, but this compiles just fine in GNAT CE 2018:

```
with Generics.Testing.Assertions;
with Generics.Testing.Assertions.Comparisons;

procedure Main is

   package Integer_Assertions is
     new Generics.Testing.Assertions
       (Integer, Wide_Wide_Image => Integer'Wide_Wide_Image);

   package Integer_Comparisons is
     new Integer_Assertions.Comparisons;

begin
   null;
end Main;
```